# Solr soft commit feature

Tags: solr

Has solr 3.6 the soft commit feature?

I read the documentation about the feature but I'm confused if only available in solr 4.0 linked with Real-Time GETS or if it's available in last stable version, the 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No according to the Solr Wiki on [soft commits](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22commit.22_and_.22optimize.22), the `softcommit` attribute of the commit command is only available in Solr version 4.0 and is *not* available in Solr version 3.6.

Comment: I'm sad, this feature is interesting, but the solr 4.0 is under development and put the 4.0 version into a production environment is not very reliable.

Comment: True, hopefully Solr 4.0 will be released within 2012!